# What are the available open source acceptors for quickfix?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

What are the available open source quickfix acceptors/servers/simulators which have MATCHING and EXECUTION option. If you any tool please give the link.

I found few tools like fiximulator,quickfix-messenger and ect. But these tools don't have order matching option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickfixJ comes with an example called OrderMatcher. It is a simple order matching engine that accepts orders and generated ER when matches occurs.